# Join to tables and show lowest price of product with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm still extremely new in Laravel and will need some help with this. Currently I have table `products` which has `category_id` column where I save from which category is each product. Another table `category` which hold `category_id`, `category_name`..

Now I want to show all category except category with id=1 on the page and show beside each category link lowest price of product in this category.

So far in my category controller I have only listing all the categories on the page but I don't know how exactly should I construct the query

This is the controller

```
$categories = Categories::paginate(15);
    return View::make('site.index', [
            'categories' => $categories
    ]); 
}
```

I have played with sql query in phpmyadmin and this is the correct query or at least return correct result..

```
SELECT price
   FROM products a
   JOIN ( 
         SELECT MIN( price ) AS minprice
         FROM products
         WHERE category_id =2
         )b 
ON a.price = b.minprice
AND a.category_id =2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it can be done using a raw statement, I don't recommend it, since Laravel provides such functionality out of the box.

You can use [Larvel's relations](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) to achieve that.

So you have a table called `category` which has a [manyToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relations with a `products` table. As in a category can have many products while at the same time a product can belong to more than one category.

You'll have to create a model for each table you have(I assume you've already done that). After which you'll have to define the relationships for the tables.

Lets assume we have a model called `ProductsModel`. Lets also assume it looks something like this:

```
class ProductsModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $fillable = [
       ...
    ];

    //Here we will define the relation between
    //this model and another model
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(
            'Namespace\To\Your\CATEGORIES\Model\Goes\Here'
            'related_foregin_key_goes_here'
        );
    }
}
```

We'll also need another model for the categories.

```
class CategoriesModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $fillable = [
       ...
    ];

    //Here we will define the relation between
    //this model and another model
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(
            'Namespace\To\Your\PRODUCTS\Model\Goes\Here',
            'related_foregin_key_goes_here'
        );
    }
}
```

Once that part is taken care of you can simply do the following:

```
$products = ProductsModel::where('category_id', '!=', 1)
    ->with('categories')
    ->min('price')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Now, I'll be perfectly honest here, my Laravel 4 skills are pretty rusty, but I think it should work just fine.

Comment: Hey, thank's for the answer but I don't get it. I have models `Products.php` and `Categories.php` i have updated them in my question. Do I need new one or I should change them.. and if I change them do they will affect other pages where I use them?

Comment: No need for new ones, these will do just fine. The changes shouldn't affect other pages unless you're specifically using said functions. Have a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many) for laravel 4 relations. I messed up my answer, I've been working with Laravel 5 recently.

Comment: I have make changes on both models and check my question how my homecontroller looks like now but I get this error : `production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function get() on a non-object' in....`

Comment: Also like i will show products not categories or I'm wrong?